# Wordpress: Caption outside of $content with catch_that_image

Tags: php, image, wordpress, captions

I needed to pull an image above the title in my wordpress pages, so I used catch_that_image (see below) But when I did this I lost my captioning ability on that image. Any idea how to add that back in? I'm thinking it has something to do with the preg_replace or preg_match and/or because it is outside of the $content ??? Here's what I've got in my functions file:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches[1][0];

if(empty($first_img)) {
  $first_img = "";
 }
return $first_img;
}
```

And in my page.php file:

```
<div class="entry-content">         
<?php

$topimg = catch_that_image(); // Find first image of Post
if($topimg) echo('<img class="top-image" src="'.$topimg.'" alt="OCF Top Image"/>');
?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h1>
<?php
$content = get_the_content('Read more');
$content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content, 1); // Remove first image of Post
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo $content;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You're mangling html with regexes... DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: could you be specific of where my regexes are? And what should I be using? I didn't write the code, just cut and pasted it. Thanks!

Comment: `preg_replace` and `preg_match_all`.. use DOM operations to manipulate html/xml.

Comment: Thanks. That's cool, duly noted, but can anyone answer my question? LOL!

Comment: Marc B, could you send me in some direction in how to change this to DOM ops? I am NOT a coder, only know enough to be dangerous...obviously.